# In Spring Boot application, how can my code be called for each custom-annotated class?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to supply a jar which, when used by clients of the jar, in a Spring Boot application, will do some specific validations of classes in the application.

My code defines some immutable BaseClass which clients may extend.
However, I only want to validate all sub-classes of BaseClass, in the application (on the classpath), which have a certain annotation which my code defines.

so for every class in the classpath of the application, which is in the hierarchy of my BaseClass and is annotated with my annotation, i want some method of my code to be called with that class passed as argument.

I guess i can somehow scan the classpath looking for these classes, but is there a better way of doing it, perhaps with aspectJ.
However, keep in mind that my code is using, and will be running in the context of, Spring Boot.

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to scan only classes that have a Spring bean or just all classes that are in the classpath (regardless if they are instantiated in the Spring context)?

Comment: the target classes will NOT be Spring Beans. They are just ordinary classes instantiated using new.

Comment: Does the annotated classes/methods extend your BaseClass? Then it wouldn't be necessary to check if they extend or not that class

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used [this Relfections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library with great success to do what you want.  That link has decent examples that match your use case.